# Creating a search bar

Tags: android, searchbar

I want to create a search bar just like the one in the [twitter app](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html).  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html

Comment: did they really use the quicksearchbox? is it possible to change the content of the quicksearchbox?

Answer (score 2):

Mainly it's a well designed view. Their designers created the images and it was put together in a view.

The application is supposed to go open source, not sure if they did yet, but once it does you could look exactly how they did it.

Comment: Well I searched for the open source but couldn't find it, 
put togther in a view ? so they didn't us ethe quick search ?

Comment: I dont think they used the quick search box if your talking about this search box: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_GTM_W5mVPTU/S-rmYdiUTCI/AAAAAAAAAEE/hIO9GD53SLc/s400/search2.png

Comment: Yes Iam talking about that searchbox, so what do u think they used?